# Rails ActiveRecord Nested Query Not Returning All Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, include

I assume this is a fairly simple syntax issue, but can't seem to solve it.

I have a query that returns a nested JSON object. In its current form, it does not return 'credits'.

```
user_data['harvests'] = @harvests.to_json(include: [ :user_public_data, :awards, comments: {include: :user}, credits: {include: :user} ])
```

However, if I reverse the order of 'credits' and 'comments', it does not return 'comments'. What's the issue here?

```
user_data['harvests'] = @harvests.to_json(include: [ :user_public_data, :awards, credits: {include: :user}, comments: {include: :user} ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to find documentation on this, but found a solution, by using as_json rather than to_json.

```
user_data['harvests'] = @harvests.as_json(include: {user_public_data: {}, awards: {}, comments: {include: :user}, credits: {include: :user} }
```